# Using two or more databases in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am using external Users database for different projects.

Now I have got School model in my project, which has_many users and users has many schools.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{RAILS_ENV}_tunnel"
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :schools, :through => :memberships
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :school
end
```

So what problems now I have:

- I can't call school.users (because membership table is in my PROJECT db, not in exernal USERS db), but I can call user.schools
- I can't update in this way: current_user.school.find(params[:id]).update_attributes(params[:school]), because It opens connection for READ ONLY in this way.

I understand how can I hack this problems, i.e.

school.users I can call like this:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  # has_many :users, :through => :memberships

  def users
    User.where("users.id in (?)", self.connections.map(&:user_id))
  end
end
```

but this hacks is not enough. Because now I can't add users like `school.users << User.find(203)`, or `school.users.find(params[:user_id])` and others features, that has_many relationship gives to me.

So **the question** is how to operate with two databases which connected to each other by many to many relationships with full feature support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is a way of doing this in Rails with full feature support - I *think* you'd be better trying to use something like [MySQL's federated tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/federated-use.html) to bring the remote DB table into your production DB.

Comment: +1 This sounds like a simpler solution, with less potential for headache.

Comment: very interesting. But how fast is synchronizing of origin and my copy of table?

Comment: @fl00r - it's not a copy of the table - it's a direct connection to the other database, so synchronisation isn't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In oracle i would be using a database link for this.

I am not entirely sure, but I found that in mysql you can write

```
select * from db1.users , db2.schools where db1.users.school_id = db2.schools.id
```

so then you would be able to use that in Rails using by explicitly stating the table-name in your model:

```
class School
  set_table_name "db2.schools"
end
```

Does that help?